# How do I animate an image to shift outside a div and return to the same position from the other side using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to animate an image inside a div to smoothly move 100px to the right, and then 'teleport' 200px left, and then smoothly move 100px right to the original position.

Like in some snake games, when you touch the wall it teleports you to the other side, or like portals. But so far I just don't know how to teleport it using @keyframes with % inside CSS.

[Here's an image to better illustrate what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0deF.jpg)

Update: New code and it works pretty nice. Thanks @CBroe

Raw HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Raw CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
}

.container .image {
    background-color: red;
    width: 50px; height: 50px;
    animation: anim 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes anim {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(500px);
    }
    50.1% {
        transform: translateX(-500px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you share us your code attempt in a working, minimal code snippet? SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: I added the code now. Sorry I'm very new to stack overflow, and I'm really not sure where to begin

Comment: Please create a proper [mre] of what you have so far. That means static HTML (no one here has your PHP/WP setup, to exactly reproduce your code otherwise), and with a publicly available image URL as well.

Comment: As for the actual problem - add more steps to your animation. Right now, you have just specified values for 0% and 100%. So, add something “in the middle” - so that the image will be moved out to the right at 50%. And then, switch that at a very small “distance” to that point - like, use `50.001%` for the next step - so that the image will be out the _left_ side of the container then, and can move back to the middle (so at 100%, you want to end up at no x transform again.)

Comment: There, I made it from scratch and followed your suggestions, and it worked pretty well. Thanks! I don't know how to do the 'run code snippit' thing, I hope this does justice